# I am unable to create an instance of EventLogAppender in log4net, even though my current log4net version is in 2.0.15?

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-appender

I am able to create and refer to AdoNetAppender and all the other different types of appenders, but i'm unable to see EventLogAppender listed under the different types of appenders also. Has it been deprecated?

I tried running visual studio as admin and tried giving user permissions but Im still unable to access EventLogAppender. The project ive created is in .NET 6 so ideally there shouldnt be an issue and I should atleast be able to see the appender as an option.